# How do I redirect after submission with acf form?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How do I redirect a user after submitting a new post using advanced custom fields form?

The documentation says:

```
<?php                    
  $args = array(
    'post_id' => 'new_1',
    'field_groups' => array( 357 ),
    'submit_value' => 'Submit Story', 
    'return' => '%post_url%'
   );
   acf_form( $args );
?>
```

But I get a blank page.

**Update after comment, still a blank page:**

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'   => 'new_post',
    'post_title'    => true,
    'post_content'  => true,
    'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink())
));
```

**Also tried this hook in function, still blank.**

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id)); exit;
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

**NOTE**

> The post is created tho

Comment: tried with  'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), ?

Comment: @vel thanks, i tried but nothing, I get a blank page. Check my question as I have updated it

Comment: Do not write exit in acf/save_post

Comment: It should return the return $post_id;

Comment: nothing, tried again, still blank :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in buffer

```
    <?php 
    /* 
    Template Name: Front 
    */ 
    ob_get_clean(); 
    acf_form_head(); 
    get_header(); 
    ?> 
    <div id="content"> 
    <?php 
    acf_form(array( 
    'post_id' => 'new_post', 
    'post_title'    => true, 
    'post_content'  => true, 
    'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', home_url() ), 
    )); 
    ?> 
    </div> 
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was building a site with [Sage 9](https://roots.io/sage/) and I had to place the acf_form_head() immediately before the `<!doctype html>` in my base.php. [@Foxaii proposed this solution](https://discourse.roots.io/t/acf-pro-frontend-form-errors-with-sage/4674) on the [Roots](https://roots.io/) forums.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, `%post_url%` seems to be malfunctioning now, but was not satisfied by a fallback to home page as proposed by `vel`.

I needed to get back to post page after edition and did the following that works like a charm:

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'   => $_GET['pid'],
    'return' => get_permalink($_GET['pid'])
));
```

Hope this helps!
Best regards